# Capybara trouble filling in JS modal

Tags: ruby, capybara, stripe-payments

Let me start by confirming that this isn't a duplicate (in that the answers posted there didn't fix my problem). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601127/capybara-is-unable-to-find-the-form-fields-from-stripe?rq=1) is essentially my exact problem: Capybara can't find the form fields in the Stripe modal to fill them in.

Here's my Capybara spec:

```
describe 'checkout', type: :feature, js: true do
  it 'checks out correctly' do
    visit '/'
    page.should have_content 'Amount: $20.00'
    page.find('#button-two').click_button 'Pay with Card'
    Capybara.within_frame 'stripe_checkout_app' do
      fill_in 'Email', with: 'example@example.com'
      fill_in 'Name',  with: 'Nick Cox'
      fill_in 'Street', with: '123 Anywhere St.'
      fill_in 'ZIP', with: '98117'
      fill_in 'City', with: 'Seattle'
      click_button 'Payment Info'
      fill_in 'Card number', with: '4242424242424242' #test card number
      fill_in 'MM/YY', with: '02/22'
      fill_in 'CVC', with: '222'
      click_button 'Pay'
    end
    page.should have_content 'Thanks'
  end
end
```

The text in that spec is my most recent attempt. **The Capybara error is `Unable to find field "Email"`**.

### What I've tried

- This most recent attempt at filling in the field by placeholder text as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601127/capybara-is-unable-to-find-the-form-fields-from-stripe?rq=1#comment33919642_20621673)
- Finding the email field by the name attribute (e.g., `fill_in 'email', with: 'example@example.com'`)
- With and without the `type: :feature` and `js: true` hashes in the `describe`
- With and without the `within_frame` call on `Capybara`
- Trying to find the input by css (e.g., `page.find('.emailInput input').set('example@example.com'`)
- Adding a `within` block: `within('.panel') do` around the form inputs (fails with `Unable to find css ".panel"`)
- Adding a `sleep 3` before the previous step in case it's looking for that div too early (fails with `Unable to find css ".panel"`)
- Adding a call to `find` (and also `page.find`) and passing the form manipulation as a block (with and without a `within` block nested in the `find` block):

```
Capybara.within_frame 'stripe_checkout_app' do
  page.find('.panel') do
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'example@example.com'
    ...
  end
end
```

I've also tried this with poltergeist.

What's maddening about this is that I've changed the Capybara driver from poltergeist back to selenium/Firefox and I can physically see the driver opening the page, clicking the button and bringing up the modal.

Any thoughts on how to get Capybara to interact with this form?

### Edit

I also tried sticking a `binding.pry` in there and debugging with the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry). The page's HTML at the point that the modal loads is a few elements, and then script tags that dynamically insert JS into the head of the iframe. See this screenshot of the DOM at the point where the `binding.pry` is hit (after the modal window opens with the Stripe form):

[image]

So that `<div class="emailInput">` is clearly in there, but `page.has_selector?('.emailInput')` returns false in the pry console.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/thenickcox/9508784) is a GitHub gist of what happens when I print `page.html` from the pry binding as the next line after `Capybara.within_frame 'stripe_checkout_app' do`. **That is, this is the markup from Capybara's perspective, and this varies wildly from the DOM as shown in the screenshot of the DOM of the actual form when it appears on screen, shown above.** As you can see, there are no inputs or anything to work with in the markup that Capybara sees.

### Update

Here is the markup for the form that contains the JS that executes the modal. (Markup is in haml).

```
  %form{ action: "/charge?amount=1400", method: 'post', class: 'payment', id: 'fourteen' }
    %article
      %label.amount
        %span Amount: $14.00

    .stripejs#button-one
      %script{ src: 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js', class:'stripe-button', :'data-key' => settings.publishable_key, :'data-name' => 'Slow Coffee', :'data-description' => '2 8oz. bags (2/month)', :'data-shipping-address' => true }
```

Comment: in this article, there are some tips for how to debug capybara tests http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: can you show me your code for model popup form, which you want to fill ?

Comment: The form HTML is dynamically generated by Stripe's JS, but you can view a screenshot of the full markup of the form [right here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/79751190@N05/13174005044/).

Comment: Assuming you're trying to fill in <input type="email" name="email" ... >... have you tried fill_in('email') [note the lower case]; also you may want to specify id="email"

Comment: nick, I have a very similar / identical problem, though cannot even get your solution working for me now. You wouldn't happen to have any other suggestions? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081305/how-to-write-integration-tests-for-stripe-checkout-on-rails

Comment: I haven't seen that timeout. Which version of Capybara are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue against [Stripe's demo checkout page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).

```
require "capybara"

sess = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
sess.visit("https://stripe.com/docs/checkout")
sess.click_button('Pay with Card')
sess.within_frame('stripe_checkout_app') do
  sess.fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@example.com' # it's visible that field becomes filled in
  sleep 3 # just to inspect that manually
end
```

The issue described by you is because there are two iframes with name `stripe_checkout_app`. `within_frame` finds the first of them that doesn't contain billing fields. To find second iframe you can do e.g.:

```
stripe_iframe = all('iframe[name=stripe_checkout_app]').last
within_frame stripe_iframe do
  # your code here
end
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/thenickcox/slow_coffee_checkout/blob/master/spec/features/app_spec.rb) is the link to the spec on GitHub. Feel free to checkout the repo and run the spec.

Comment: BTW, I think the bounty only has an hour left. Sorry if it closes before you provide a working answer. If that's the case, I'll see if I can start another and award it to you.

Comment: Thanks! Just commented on the issue.

Comment: Also, I just tried your code to repro, and you're absolutely right; that field is filled in!

Comment: I noticed that this instantiates Capybara::Session. I don't see that in the docs anywhere. Is my config wrong in my [spec_helper.rb](https://github.com/thenickcox/slow_coffee_checkout/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb)?

Comment: I also tried instantiating Capybara::Session in that same way in my test, and now I get `Unable to locate frame: stripe_checkout_app`, although it's clearly on the page, and the same example works on the Stripe site.

Comment: @nickcoxdotme You don't need to instantiate session manually. It becomes available in your spec when you `require 'capybara/rspec'`

Comment: @nickcoxdotme Session becomes available in your specs by including `Capybara::DSL` - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L8

Answer (score 5):

Don't have 50 rep to comment but, have you tried adding some wait time on capybara so the modal has time to load completely, I came across a similar problem using testcafe and giving it 2-3 seconds wait time did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for at least trying. See #7 of things I tried with a `sleep 3`. Unless you tried it another way?

Comment: did you try `page.find('.checkout')` ?

Comment: Just did. `Unable to find css ".checkout"`. I tried it after the `sleep 3` also. I noticed that Capybara has an `execute_script` method, but I wasn't able to get that to do anything. It's just baffling to me how different the page markup is. (See the gist of the HTML.)

Comment: @gimiarn1801 Here's some rep to help you get to 50.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out an idea here, since I've been stuck on these little idiosyncratic problems and know how frustrating they can be....Once I was just trying to get Capybara to click a "Close" button on a Twitter Bootstrap modal dialog box.  It turns out that to get it to work, I had to enclose the Bootstrap modal html code in a "form" tag and then Capybara was able to find it.  I wonder if something like that is  your issue?

Comment: That's an interesting thought. See haml markup, above. Would you suggest wrapping the `script` tag in a div and doing something like `find('div.script-container') do`?

Comment: Ah, edited the response to say put the code that is responsible for generating the  modal in a "form" tag.  SOverflow hid the "<form>" part of my answer.

Comment: Hm…So you can see in my haml that the `script` tag is in a `form` tag. Is that similar to what your situation was? What was it that generated the modal for you?

Comment: My modal code was static HTML & was similar to what is under the section "the hack" in this post: http://www.binarywebpark.com/javascript-testing-with-cucumber-capybara-poltergeist-phantomjs-and-the-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dialog-box/  Can you use static HTML for the modal and see what happens?  Have you tried changing Capybara.default_wait_time to something longer than 2 sec?

Answer (score 0):

Capybara fill_in uses css ids not classes. Example

`<input autofocus="autofocus" class="center" id="user_login" name="user[login]" placeholder="Username/Email" type="text" >`

You may also have to use `<input>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: `fill_in` can also use a `name` attribute, which I tried (See "What I've Tried", step 2).

Comment: Yes, but it's still looking for the css id object not class.

Answer (score -1):

Try with Poltergeist, using the Window Switching methods

https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#window-switching

```
stripe = page.driver.window_handles.last

page.within_window stripe do
  fill_in "Email", :with => "test@test.com"

  fill_in 'Card number', with: '4242424242424242' #test card number
  fill_in 'MM / YY', with: '02/22'
  fill_in 'CVC', with: '222'

  click_button 'Pay'
end
```

I found the solution in this spanish blog: [numerica latina](http://www.numerica.cl/2014/02/debugear-webkit-como-driver-de-capybara/).